# Symbolic expression of difference equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math

How can I solve following difference equation in Matlab:

A(n+1) = (1-i*p)A(n)

where *p* is arbitrary constant and A(0) = A0?

The answer obtained by iteration method of the equation is A(n) = A0*(1-i*p)^(n).

But how we can obtain this answer in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest i could get. (its not possible to make condition on symbolic variable):

```
syms A0 C real
% assume(in(k,'integer') & k>0);
k=90;
Ak=MyFun(A0,C,k) %Output: A0*C^90

function Ak=MyFun(A0,C,k)
    if k<1
        Ak=A0;
    else
        Ak=C*MyFun(A0,C,k-1);
    end
end
```